# How the the metrics work on the Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discusión, site-evaluation

For example in the last [Site Self Evaluation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/lets-get-critical-dec-2013-site-self-evaluation#answer-326)

There are posted question with the following metrics:

> Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

What does they mean and work?

- Net Score
- Excellent
- Satisfactory
- Need Improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We recently fixed the second link.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204091/link-to-the-self-evaluation-review-queue-returns-404-at-the-end-of-the-self-eval)  It's now possible to read the help text for the review queue after the review is over:

> Run comparative Google searches on these questions and see if the content is better or worse than what is already out there on the internet. Are the answers correct, clear, useful and informative? Would the question and answer be interesting to the kind of user this site is trying to attract? Choose:
>
> - **Excellent** if this question is well-written and has a clear, comprehensive answer that is far better than other available resources. This question shows up early in search results.
> - **Satisfactory** if this question has a clear, comprehensive answer that is comparable or better than the information found elsewhere. This question shows up later in the search results or requires oddly specific search terms to find.
> - **Needs Improvement** if this question is poorly written, not generally useful, or has an answer that is no better than what can be found elsewhere. Alternatively, this question does not turn up on the first page or two in Google despite repeated search attempts.
> - **Skip** if you are not sure and want to go to the next question
>
> Discuss these questions here and share your thoughts and comments with others!
>
> *About this queue: This review queue appears periodically on sites to evaluate the overall quality of the Q&A. After a few days, this queue will disappear until it is time for the next quality review.*

Comment: thanks for the update

Comment: Did you know somenthing about the StackOverflow in spanish? some update?

Comment: @Emilio Gort: We have no immediate plans for es.SO.  The Portuguese site just entered public beta this week.  We are trying to hire a Japanese speaker to be Community Manager for a Japanese site.  After that, it largely depends on: a) how successful localized SO sites are and b) how much value we can add for programmers in a particular language.  I suspect Spanish is relatively high on the list, but we don't know yet.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.