# Intentando averiguar por qué tenemos tan pocas preguntas por día

Tags: discusión, preguntas, promoción-de-la-comunidad

> **Descargo de responsabilidad**: no me hago responsable de los microinfartos cerebrales por leer una pregunta tan densa un lunes por la mañana.

He visto en las [estadísticas del Área 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) (y se ha notado además) que el número de preguntas por día está ahora mismo en 2.4. No sé si es el verano o yo qué sé, pero definitivamente algo tenemos que hacer con eso. He estado curioseando las [estadísticas de Japanese language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7526/japanese-language) en el momento en el que se graduó hace un año, y en comparación con las nuestras eran las siguientes:

```
                    Japanese    Spanish
Questions/day       7.9         2.4
Answered            99%         99%
Avid (total) users  453 (7475)  438 (9445)
Answer ratio        1.6         2.3
Visits/day          4808        11764
```

Después de pasado un tiempo, creo que el [code-golf](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) solo nos ha ayudado en el número de visitas al día, y ni de eso estoy seguro, porque la tendencia de visitas ha ido siempre al alza.

En todo caso, adonde yo quiero ir es a lo siguiente: tenemos unas estadísticas similares o mejores a las de Japanese Language, excepto la del número de preguntas al día. No quiero intentar proponer mejoras aquí al respecto, que para eso ya [se me ha adelantado el señor aparente](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2632/12637), pero está claro que ese aspecto es el único que hay que mejorar si queremos salir de beta (que igual no queremos, no sé). Yo lo que quería es intentar analizar las causas.

¿A qué se debe tan poca curiosidad por el idioma español?

- ¿La gente no nos conoce? No puede ser, tenemos más del doble de visitas al día que Japanese Language cuando se graduó.
- ¿Los hispanohablantes somos más bien parados? Dicen que [el idioma forja hasta cierto punto la personalidad](https://www.linguisticsociety.org/content/does-language-i-speak-influence-way-i-think), e incluso que una misma persona puede tener comportamientos diferentes según el idioma que necesite hablar en ese momento. A lo mejor al hablar español uno se hace más contemplativo.
- ¿La religión católica incita al conformismo? Hay estudios que afirman que [los países de creencias protestantes tienden a ser más avanzados](https://www.theguardian.com/education/2011/oct/31/economics-religion-research), dado que llevan a sus estudiantes a cursar estudios de más alto grado (de media) que los católicos. Pero incluso así, el español es uno de los idiomas más estudiado en todo el mundo. Incluso si fuera cierto que los hispanohablantes somos conformistas, ¿qué pasa con el resto del mundo? ¿No tienen preguntas para nosotros?
- ¿Somos estrictos con las normas? ¿Asustamos a los nuevos? Tenemos básicamente las mismas normas que el resto de sitios dedicados a los idiomas, y los que nos conocen dicen que solemos tener un trato generalmente más amable.
- ¿La RAE nos quita el trabajo? En otros países no hay una entidad tan magna y regia como la RAE, por lo que las preguntas pueden debatirse más y a veces no son tan obvias porque un diccionario dirá una cosa y otro dirá otra. Nosotros descartamos muchas preguntas porque lo que dice la RAE va a misa, y no suele haber más debate. O incluso es que como la RAE cae bien, la gente directamente pregunta a la RAE (por Twitter, por ejemplo; nosotros mismos lo hacemos cuando no somos capaces de resolver la pregunta). ¿Podría ser hora de empezar a discutirle a la RAE?
- ¿Ya hemos planteado todas las preguntas más obvias? Igual después de tantos años ya hemos planteado todas las dudas principales del idioma, que la gente entra a consultar (de ahí el número de visitas al día), y ya solo quedan las dudas complicadas, más difíciles de encontrar y responder.
- ¿El idioma español es tan fácil que la gente lo aprende sin tener casi dudas? Anda ya, si las tengo yo constantemente...
- ¿La gente que empieza se pierde con las etiquetas traducidas al español? Y quien dice las etiquetas, dice cualquier otra cosa que solo esté en español en el sitio, no me he parado a hacer un repaso exhaustivo.
- ¿Somos unos *agarraos*? Creo que puedo contar con los dedos las manos las recompensas que he visto pasar a lo largo del año que llevo aquí. ¿Tanto apego le tenemos a nuestros puntos de reputación? ¿O tal vez es que no hacemos preguntas lo suficientemente complicadas para las que merezca la pena abrir una recompensa? ¿O es que sabemos que las recompensas se pierden porque la gente no participa?

Así pues, y como tema de análisis para apoyar la pregunta del señor aparente, ¿cuáles pueden ser las causas de que se planteen tan pocas preguntas aquí?

Comment: A mi también me preocupa que a veces parecemos _agarraos_. Ya hace tiempo pregunté [si se vota poco en este stack](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5481) (o si solo me lo parece a mi). Es cierto que es muy subjetivo qué hace una buena pregunta o respuesta, pero creo que si algunos post no se valoran/recompensan como se merecen (sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que los stacks están _ludificados_) eso puede desanimar a mucha gente a participar, especialmente para posts o contribuciones no triviales (que no saldrían "a cuenta").

Comment: @Diego yo creo que la gente no vota por lo buena o mala que sea la pregunta. A veces hacemos preguntas dignas de tesis doctorales, pero no se votan porque no son **útiles**. En cambio, fíjate en [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21130/12637). Apenas 39 visitas y una respuesta con 9 votos. La pregunta era divertida, cayó en gracia, la respuesta era curiosa y la gente la votó. Me he fijado que pasa sobre todo con las preguntas hechas en inglés: si consiguen entrar en las HNQ y tratan un tema que atraiga la curiosidad general, se votará mucho.

Comment: @Diego eso nos deja con el resto de preguntas: las cotidianas del día a día que no consiguen atraer al gran público. Según cómo se establecen las medallas de bronce, plata y oro, se espera que una respuesta útil tenga unos 5 votos de media (ejemplo: para medalla de bronce hacen falta 20 respuestas en un tema con 100 votos en total). Sin embargo esa media no se cumple aquí, y generalmente se llega mucho antes a las 20 respuestas que a los 100 votos. Conclusiones: o nuestras respuestas no son lo suficientemente útiles, o realmente la gente vota como si les costara dinero de verdad.

Comment: Yo personalmente creo que la principal razón es que hay una competencia llamada WordReference (https://forum.wordreference.com/) con mas de 75.5 K de preguntas en español con 15 hilos activos al día, cumple el mismo propósito que este StackEchange pero tiene como 20 años más, de todos modos, creo que es cosa de tiempo para que esto se vaya haciendo más conocido.

Answer (score 4):

El motivo que apuntas sobre la RAE me parece bastante interesante. Añadiría también la Fundéu. Ambas instituciones tienen mucho prestigio entre los hispanohablantes y, por su actividad aclarando dudas y haciendo propuestas, probablemente cubran una buena parte de lo que en otros idiomas hace el foro equivalente a este. Esto puede actuar en detrimento de la actividad del foro, pero es bueno para el lenguaje.

Comment: Ciertamente, luego lo he pensado y el Twitter de la RAE no para de recibir preguntas, imagino que también las recibirán por otros medios. La diferencia es que ellos responden CUALQUIER pregunta, incluyendo las que nosotros aquí rechazaríamos (por el motivo que fuere) y aunque se la hayan hecho ya en otras ocasiones. Incluso responden a los trolls, y gracias a eso se han labrado la simpatía de la gente. Así que no es que no haya dudas sobre el idioma, es que la RAE nos hace una competencia atroz.

Comment: Eso sí, muchas veces he visto a la RAE responder en Twitter que esa pregunta no entra dentro de su ámbito. Podríamos hablar con ellos para que en esos casos redirigiesen a la gente a este sitio, ya que ellos solo tratan el español actual (vocabulario, ortografía y gramática) y nosotros tratamos temas más amplios. Puede ser un propósito elevado, pero por probar...

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¿y no sería interesante conseguir algún tipo de "convenio" con ellos? Aunque solo fuera inicialmente cierto compromiso por nuestra parte de ofrecer explicaciones largas y detalladas que ellos pudieran utilizar. La diferencia de tamaño y relevancia también es atroz, pero con el tiempo [so] ha conseguido que multitud de empresas la adopten como servicio de preguntas-respuestas.

Comment: @fedorqui tu comentario se ha pisado con el segundo mío, aunque veo que se nos ha ocurrido la misma idea... :-D

Comment: @fedorqui me gustaría probar a escribirles, ¿a qué departamento dirigirías la carta? Opciones: Dirección, Secretaría, Gerencia, Biblioteca, Archivo, Tecnología, Comunicación, Comercial, Publicaciones. ¿Al de comunicación, tal vez? ¿O al de tecnología? ¿O se la mandamos al director? :-D

Comment: @CarlosAlejo ¡Ostras, ahora lo veo! _Great minds think alike..._ :) Pues se me ocurren muchas opciones: o bien contactarles algo informalmente vía Twitter pues son quienes lidian con el día a día, o bien dirigirnos a instancias superiores. También sería interesante si [se] se pudiera involucrar, pues puede ser más iluminador recibir la petición de parte de alguien que habla en nombre de una página que tiene 11 mil visitas diarias en Spanish y muchos millones en general. ¿Qué te parece a ti?

Comment: @fedorqui me parece que podríamos hablar del tema en un chat. :-)

Comment: ¿Recuperemos pues [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia)?

Comment: Tu reflexión se merece mi enhorabuena y aplauso: "Esto puede actuar en detrimento de la actividad del foro, pero es bueno para el lenguaje". ¡Efectivamente!

Answer (score 3):

Pues a ver...

#### ¿La gente no nos conoce?

Está claro que tenemos muchas visitas.
La pregunta es: las visitas que recibimos ¿son de gente que *sabe* que puede hacer preguntas? ¿O son solamente de gente que llega aquí a través de Google cuando están buscando algo, sin conocer realmente de qué va esto? ¿O son bots?
A la vista del ratio votos/visitas y "question views"/visitas, yo me inclino por la segunda: la gente entra sin saber de qué va esto y, peor aún, se van sin haber entendido el sentido del sitio.

- Solución: atraer usuarios que, cuando entren, ya sepan de qué va esto. Publicitar el sitio, no depender de Google. Intentar hacer preguntas atractivas como para salir en Hot Network Questions.

#### ¿Los hispanohablantes somos más bien parados?

¿[En qué sentido](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=RpbTVdu)? Jajajaja :D
No... pero creo que sí tenemos mucho más **[pundonor](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=pundonor)** que otras culturas, en el sentido de que evitamos a toda costa hacer preguntas si hacerlas puede llevar a que los demás piensen que no sabemos algo (en la escuela, o cuando no sabemos cómo llegar a un lugar, o...).
Esto se refleja en refranes como *"Más vale callar y parecer tonto, que abrir la boca y demostrarlo"*.

- Solución: ninguna.

#### ¿La religión católica incita al conformismo?

Puede. El simple hecho de que exista la RAE puede ser influencia católica, con su tendencia a regular el modo en que pensamos, vivimos... y hablamos.
Otros idiomas de países no católicos son más laxos en cuanto a las normas del lenguaje, eso es cierto.
Yo lo relacionaría más bien con el pundonor mencionado antes. Al fin y al cabo, la influencia de la religión católica es un rasgo de la cultura hispanohablante.

- Solución: ninguna.

#### ¿Somos estrictos con las normas? ¿Asustamos a los nuevos?

Posiblemente. Que seamos amables no quiere decir que nuestra amabilidad no genere rechazo.
Ejemplo: los misioneros mormones son muy amables pero a nadie le hace gracia que, a poco que les mires, te suelten la parrafada.
A mí a veces me da la sensación de que hacemos un poco lo mismo: llega alguien, dice algo que no se ajusta muy bien a lo que esperamos, y ¡hale! Comentario de 5 líneas con 4 enlaces diciendo que su contribución es mejorable.
Aunque sean comentarios amables y bien intencionados, puede que a algunos usuarios les "chafe" un poco.
Además, no nos engañemos: si filtramos demasiado las preguntas que llegan, de manera que todo lo que ve un usuario nuevo son Buenas Preguntas ™ (con varios párrafos, enlaces, definiciones, ejemplos y demás)... es harto probable que se sientan cohibidos y que piensen que su pregunta no está a la altura del sitio. Idem para las respuestas.

- Solución: dejar que los votos negativos hagan su trabajo. Permitir la existencia de respuestas erróneas o de mala calidad. La [Ley de Cunningham](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law/es) dice que "***la mejor manera de que te respondan a una pregunta, es publicar una respuesta errónea y esperar a que venga alguien a corregirte***". Moderar (esto incluye los comentarios de las colas de review) solo las que reporten los usuarios o las que rompan la armonía del sitio.

#### ¿La RAE nos quita el trabajo?

¡Oh, sin duda!
A veces me planteo montar un *bot* que se dedique a publicar aquí todas las preguntas que le hacen a la RAE en Twitter. Si nosotros mismos acudimos a ellos a veces, con más razón quien no conoce el sitio.
Es un buen punto el que planteas, sobre dar más relevancia a temas que la RAE no toca o [que considera erróneos aunque no "tod@s" estén de acuerdo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21887/13628).

- Solución: ninguna sencilla. Montar una brigada que responda a los que preguntan a la RAE, indicando que pueden preguntar aquí también. Publicar nosotros mismos esas preguntas. Lo del bot entiendo que no sería adecuado (ni tengo tiempo tampoco, pero si alguien se anima...).

#### ¿Ya hemos planteado todas las preguntas más obvias?

Si atendemos a lo planteado en el primer punto, sobre que la mayoría de usuarios llegan de Google buscando solo una respuesta y se van sin preguntar nada más, puede que efectivamente tengamos tantas preguntas resueltas que casi todos encuentran lo que buscan. Pero creo que, si así fuera, nos cansaríamos de cerrar preguntas duplicadas, y no es el caso.
Esto se podría comprobar revisando la evolución de las visitas a las preguntas más consultadas, supongo.

- Solución: ninguna buena.

#### ¿El idioma español es tan fácil que la gente lo aprende sin tener casi dudas?

[Va a ser que no](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyGFz-zIjHE).

#### ¿La gente que empieza se pierde con las etiquetas traducidas al español?

Interesante. Podría ser.
¿Hay estadísticas del ratio de preguntas anterior a la "españolización", para comparar?
Quizá deberíamos poner al menos las descripciones de los tags en inglés también.

- Solución: revisar la política sobre el idioma principal del sitio o de los tags en particular.

#### ¿Somos unos agarraos?

Esto en todo caso afectaría al ratio de respuestas, no al de preguntas :D
Creo que en este sitio, si una pregunta tiene respuesta, la obtiene sin necesidad de recompensa. Y si no tiene, no va a aparecer una mágicamente por el hecho de regalar puntos. Yo al menos lo veo así.
En otros sitios como StackOverflow, donde puedes hacer una pregunta relativamente sencilla y que pasen semanas sin que nadie te haga caso, o donde la variedad de tecnologías y formas de hacer las cosas es alta, tiene sentido ofrecer recompensas para conseguir respuestas buenas; aquí, que tenemos un 100% de preguntas respondidas, y aún diría que casi todas satisfactoriamente, las recompensas pierden un poco su sentido.

- Solución: no creo que sea un problema que necesite una.

Comment: Buena respuesta. Las [fuentes de tráfico](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) son ahora mismo la búsqueda desde Google (91%), acceso desde otro sitio de la red (apenas 0,8%) y acceso directo (7,7%). En [so] el acceso directo es bastante menor (2,1%) pero desde la red recibe bastante más (2,3%). Parece que estamos perdiendo SEO para Google (antes [salíamos primeros en algún caso](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/330/1674)), lo que hace pensar que quien entra, sale rápido. Podríamos sacar datos en Data explorer sobre retención de usuarios, nos falla mucho.

Answer (score 2):

I have been visiting the site for a while now and enjoyed reading. I have also asked a few questions but recently my flow has dried up. One reason is that as I have read other answers I have an increased repertoire of resources. When I started I did not even know the RAE had a dictionary online. A second reason is that many of the questions have already been answered at least approximately in existing answers.

I am not sure whether having tags only in Spanish puts people off but if you look at the front page most of the questions have Spanish language titles. When I last looked 8 out of 50 were in English (apart from quoting a English word or phrase for translation). So a casual browser might think that this is just a site for those who can write Spanish. I cannot be the only user who can read, speak and understand but has never had any pressing need to learn to write in Spanish.

Comment: I suggest to remove any reference to dictionaries, so we are the only source of information :)) Jokes aside, this is an interesting insight! Increasing the number of questions in English can attract more people _learning_ the language. The debate is whether we "want" this profile or we prefer more academic, Spanish native speakers. The best would be to have both groups, of course.